# Как получить значение select?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как исправить скрипт, чтобы при выборе числа 2, у нас срабатывало условие.

```js
$(function() {
   var test = $('select').val();
   if (test === 2 ) {
        alert('Выбрано второе значение');
   } else {
      alert('Выбрано другое значение');
   }
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('select').on("change",function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if (val == 2 ) {
        alert('Выбрано второе значение');
   } else {
      alert('Выбрано другое значение');
   }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```