# JS - Получить значение из select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На сайте есть несколько `select`, которые выводятся в цикле:

```js
$(".selectOptions").change(function() {
  var href = $(".selectOptions :selected").val();
  console.log(href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="6" class="color form-control ocf-target selected selectOptions" name="color">

       <option class="ir_Все" value="http://.../index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=59" id="v-cancel-1">Все</option>
       <option class="ir_3597ae" value="" id="v-12" disabled="disabled">Синий</option>
       <option class="ir_ffffff" value="http://.../index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=59&amp;filter_ocfilter=1:22" id="v-122">Белый</option>
                                                                                                        
    </select>


<select size="6" class="color form-control ocf-target selected selectOptions" name="color">

       <option class="ir_fbaf00" value="http://.../index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=59&amp;filter_ocfilter=1:3" id="v-13" selected="selected">Желтый</option>
       <option class="ir_ff0000" value="" id="v-11" disabled="disabled">Красный</option>
                                                                                                        
    </select> ...
```

Необходимо при выборе какого-либо поля, получить значение этого поля.
Но почему то берет значение только из первого `select`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить значение select?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595591/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-select)

Comment: @splash58, `disabled="disabled"` увы оно должно быть там

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".selectOptions").change(function() 
{
    var href = $(this).val();
    console.log(href);
});
```